# Intellij: Scala - find all pattern matches on a certain class

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, ide, pattern-matching

In intellij, is there any way to find all statements `arg match{ ... }` (anywhere in the project) where `arg` is of a certain class?

**Edit**

Just to be clear, I'm not interested in all matches. Say `A` is a class, then I should like to find all matches `arg match {...}` where `arg:A`.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, your best shot is to do a find in path with custom attributes like specifying path, file type and a regex containing "match" keyword. You can then isolate through the results.

Comment: That just finds all matches. Not really what the OP was asking for, I think